# PHP Sort Ascending Keeping Identical Keys

Tags: php, sorting

I am working with a php associative array and i want to sort in ascending order on array key...But it is removing identical keys and keeping one key.

### Here is my code

```
<?php   
 $num = [
    100 => 75, 
    45  => 89,
    120 => 101,
    120 => 121,
    120 => 11,
 ];  
 asort($num );
 print_r($num);
```

But result is `Array ( [120] => 11 [100] => 75 [45] => 89 )`
I want the output is ascending manner `Array ( [120] => 11 [100] => 75 [45] => 89 [120] => 121 [120] => 101)`
I want to keep all 3 key value pair with the key `120`. How can i do it?

Comment: what output you want?

Comment: how did you reach this data structure?

Comment: You can't. `$num` is not a valid PHP array; successive values with the same key will overwrite the prior ones.

Comment: Are you certain that you can have multiple identical _keys_ in an array? What output do expect if you `echo $num[120]`?

Comment: In PHP, you cannot have duplicate keys in an array. If you remove the sorting, you'll notice only the last entry with key '120' will be present. See [this page in the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Comment: @KUMAR Array ( [120] => 11 [120] => 101  [120] => 121 [100] => 75 [45] => 89) . I want to keep all the identical keys.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is not valid in PHP; arrays cannot have more than one value with the same key. One alternative would be to use a multi-dimensional array, for example:

```
$num = [
    [100 => 75], 
    [45  => 89],
    [120 => 101],
    [120 => 121],
    [120 => 11],
];
```

This can then be sorted with `usort`:

```
usort($num, function ($a, $b) { return reset($a) - reset($b); });
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [120] => 11
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [100] => 75
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [45] => 89
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [120] => 101
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [120] => 121
        )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/QlDdK)

You can work with this array using a foreach loop, for example:

```
foreach ($num as $arr) {
    echo key($arr) . ' => ' . reset($arr) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
120 => 11
100 => 75
45 => 89
120 => 101
120 => 121
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/guPZI)

Answer (score 1):

An array key is by definition of being a `key`, unique. You can not have multiple parts of data saved under the same key. In PHP the later values simply overwrite the previous ones.

[From the Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

> If multiple elements in the array declaration use the same key, only the last one will be used as all others are overwritten.

What you *can* do, is have that key full of sub-array of other values. This will require the method of creating your current data structure to be updated but could output something like:

So;

```
 $num = [
    100 => 75, 
    45  => 89,
    120 => [ 0 => 101,
             1 => 121,
             2 => 11]
 ];  
 asort($num );
 print_r($num);
```

I would give you an example of how to construct this but would like to have your own code to work from first.